# CentOS 7 to 8, now apache issue

Tags: apache, centos, cpanel

I successfully got CentOS 8 installed from CentOS 7.

However, now it seems that there is an issue with Apache.

I can load WHM (cPanel) successfully, and go into the Apache settings - when I try to restart it I get:

"An unknown error occurred."

Everything else seems to be working OK (Email, FTP)

Should I attempt to uninstall & re-install it? Or what would my best course of action be?
Apologies for the newbie question. I am indeed a Newbie to CentOS.

Thank you for your help

I tried rebooting the server.
Checking if Apache was running.
What the difference between apache and httpd is

Comment: I did nothing other than restart the machine, and now web / email doesn't work either. Looks like a fresh install will be required here.